# How do I write and if the statement evaluating two columns in r

Tags: r

I need to replace the value in Account with the Value in UserID if the Value in account is blank.

Example

```
My.data
Account         UserID     Message
NULL            123456     Pass
NULL            234567     Fail
3456789         adamO      Pass
4567890         EveOO      Fail
```

Cleaned Data

```
My.Data2
Account         UserID     Message
123456          123456     Pass
2345667         234567     Fail
3456789         adamO      Pass
4567890         EveOO      Fail
```

Essentially if `My.Data$Account` is `null` then put `My.Data$UserID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have 'character' "NULL" values instead of the actual 'NULL', we create a logical index of 'NULL' values in the 'Account' column and using that we replace the 'Account' values with the corresponding values in 'UserID'

```
  indx <-  My.data$Account=='NULL'
  My.data$Account[indx] <- My.data$UserID[indx]
  My.data
  #  Account UserID Message
  #1  123456 123456    Pass
  #2  234567 234567    Fail
  #3 3456789  adamO    Pass
  #4 4567890  EveOO    Fail
```

A similar code with `data.table` would be

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(My.data)[Account=='NULL', Account:=UserID]
```

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(My.data)`), and assign 'Account' that are 'NULL' with the corresponding 'UserID'.

#### data

```
 My.data <- structure(list(Account = c("NULL", "NULL", "3456789",
 "4567890"
 ), UserID = c("123456", "234567", "adamO", "EveOO"), Message = c("Pass", 
 "Fail", "Pass", "Fail")), .Names = c("Account", "UserID", "Message"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I am getting a warning message :        data$AccountNumber[indx] <- data$SciUserID[indx]
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, indx, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: @AllyKat You have a `factor` column.  If you look at my data, it is all character.  With factor columns, it is more difficult to replace values unless you have that level specified for that column.  I would conver the columns to 'character', i...e. My.data[] <- lapply(My.data, as.character)` and apply the code

Comment: that worked but what if I want to keep 1 of 4 columns as a number for later manipulation?

Comment: @AllyKat Sorry I didn't get your comment.  If you need the original dataset as intact, `My.data1 <-  My.data` and do the changes on the copied dataset.

Answer (score 0):

dplyr version:

```
require(dplyr)
my.data2 <- mutate(my.data,ifelse(Account== "NULL", UserID, Account))
```